# Preload jQuery slideDown animation before displaying content

Tags: jquery, slide

I have a navigation menu that use jQuery `slideUp` and `slideDown` to show or hide sub-menus.

My page saves the state of the menu and which submenus they had expanded when the user navigates different pages. My problem is that when the page loads it loads the whole `slideDown` animation too, the menu starts fully collapased and the relevant sub-menu(s) expand

I do not want this as it is distracting. If loading a saved menu state I want the menu item to appear with the `slideDown`transition already complete. Is there a way of preloading this?

Comment: In the scenario where you are restoring state, just set the animation duration to zero.

Comment: @Fresheyeball This has worked perfectly. So simple - thanks. If you want to add as an answer I can marked it for you.

Comment: Ok. I made it an answer. Please accept so I can get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario where you are restoring state, just set the animation duration to zero.